# Image share (post) on facebook from resourse drawable folder

Tags: android, facebook, image, android-intent, share

I am making an application for which I need to share an image with text on facebook timeline. However with my code i can share a link to the facebook wall but cannot share Image. I already tried most of the code of stack overflow. but not succeed yet. Here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.test2;



import com.facebook.android.Facebook;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String[] ShareOption;
Spinner ShareOptionList;
int driverStarScore = 1; //2 or 3 ...
Facebook facebookClient;    
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

ListView list;

 String[] ShareItemName ={

 "Dropbox",
 "Email",
 "Facebook",
 "Google Plus",
 "Twitter",
 "Whatsapp",

 };

 Integer[] ShareImageId={

         R.drawable.ic_dropbox,
         R.drawable.ic_email,
         R.drawable.ic_facebook,
         R.drawable.ic_googleplus,
         R.drawable.ic_twitter,
         R.drawable.ic_whatsapp,

         };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






    ShareOptionList=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_ShareScore);
    ShareOption=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ShareChooseOption);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ShareOption);
    ShareOptionList.setAdapter(adapter1);

    ShareOptionList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int index=arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You select "+ ShareOption[index],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });




    ShareListAdapter adapter=new ShareListAdapter(this, ShareItemName, ShareImageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_share);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String Selecteditem= ShareItemName[+position];

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Selecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         if(Selecteditem=="Facebook"){  


            // if (driverStarScore == 1){
                 //Uri pngUri = Uri.parse("file//res/drawable/star_1.png");
            // }
             //if (driverStarScore == 2){
                // Uri pngUri = Uri.parse("file//res/drawable/star_2.png");
        // }

            String urlToShare = "http://tinypic.com/r/16gil4y/8";

             try {

                    Intent facebook1 = new Intent();
                    facebook1.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ImplicitShareIntentHandler");
                    facebook1.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
                    facebook1.setType("image/png");
                    facebook1.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", urlToShare);
                    startActivity(facebook1);

             } catch (Exception e) {
                    // If we failed (not native FB app installed), try share through SEND
                    Intent facebook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
                    facebook = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
                    startActivity(facebook);
                }


         }
         if(Selecteditem=="Email"){
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            email.setType("message/rfc822");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"}); // if you want to add email address also.
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sample Text");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Driving Score Email");

            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         }

        }
         });



}
```

/**
    * 
    */

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }





@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.test2"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="16"
                android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".Menu"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Menu" />
                        <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

              <activity
                        android:name="com.sample.socialshare.facebookUpload"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        </intent-filter>
                </activity>


                        </application>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>


        </manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended, and easier, way to sharing things with Facebook is using the [Android Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android). 
You can find documentation about how to [integrate it with your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) and [how to share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) on the Facebook Developer site.

Note: Calling directly the sharing dialog, although it works, is unsupported and can break at any time, so it is definitely not recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually I am very new in android application development. I have already seen the facebook page for share features. but the procedure is not clear to me. Do you have any specific procedure to share image with text from my application on facebook.  @Rafael

Comment: @nowshinrea, to share an image you can use either a [ShareButton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareButton/) or directly a [ShareDialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareDialog/). It is pretty well explained in the Sharing page on the documentation.
Anyway I recommend you to try and if you have any problem open a new bug with the new code.